# Sync database from desktop system to remote server and vice versa?

Tags: c#, mysql, synchronization, database

I make a application, which has to interfaces.  one is desktop and other is web application.
both have their own databases (which are same is structure). 

I want to **sync** the **database from desktop to remote server** and also from **remote server to desktop** but i have no idea that how it does.

I use the **MYSql** database. and my desktop application is in .NET
NOTE: There are **more than one** destop systems who update their databases and also sync databases.

Comment: ... Why would you make this CW?

Answer (score 0):

you can write an application that delete the common data between your db and destination db from destination db, after that copy all of your data from db to your destination db.
by this work you can have a updated data in every time that you do this work.